# Cygwin terminal does not export png files when it is imported by script.sh

Tags: shell, cygwin, png

I am running a code on cygwin terminal in windows 8. I import  in this code 2 images (png format) and some parameters and it exports a txt file and an png image. I wanted to run this code a lot of times in order to change the parameteres that i import. So I made a script.sh by notepad++ where each line is my command line with changed parameters. The problem is that when I run the script.sh in does not export the image(png) and it says "file type not supported", but when i run the code directly in terminal it exports the png image. Do you have any idea how i can solve this?

I provide the code

./mrfstereo -n 74 -t 16 -a 1 -m 1 -l 15 -g 20 -p 3 -w 2005/Art/art_L.png 2005/Art/art_R.png 2005/Art/1.expansion/trunc-dif/m=1/l=15/g=20/p=3/t=16.png

mrfstereo is the main code. After that are the parameters I change, then the 2 images I import and then the path where It will save the t=16.png image. In each line of the script i Created is this command by different parameters.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Please provide even any code to help you

Comment: Please put the code into your question and format it properly

Comment: Make sure your `notepad++` settings for `Settings->Preferences->New File->Format (Line Ending)`  have `Unix (LF)` selected.